# Why did the mission control go down?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In Interstellar, Cooper mentions that

> "Delhi mission control went down same as ours".

Could you explain why the mission control was down? And it seems to be explained in the first space craft crash scene, cooper was dreaming about. But I can't get the audio clearly.

Comment: *"And it seems to be explained in the first space craft crash scene, cooper was dreaming about"* - No, that seems totally unrelated thereto.

Answer (score 6):

If this is what I think you're referring to, he's talking about the space programs being decommissioned...

By saying the Delhi mission control "went down", he's stating that because of the global push for technology and agriculture that will help humanity survive, the space programs were considered too costly and unnecessary: and were shut down.